# access denied page

Tags: office-365

I have a new sharepoint site from a client, if I enter in the server as admin and open Central administration I can see my site, but if I try to access from outside (via internet) to the server or via IIS admin it accepts my credentials but then redirect me to a access denied page. What I have to do to enable my user?

Comment: Is it on prem installation of sharepoint? did you add your user into the farm admin group of Central admin?

Comment: yes I added me, but it doesnt worked until I added myself to the user policy of the root site. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I added myself in the user policy of the root web 80 and it works.

Comment: then this is not a solution...adding yourself in Policy for web...what about the other uses, will you add all into the user policy for web app?

Comment: I don't understand what you say, excuse me. I added like you said myself in farm admin group, but it doesn't solved the problem, it only allows me to view the site in my server but if I try to access it from outside the server it doesnt works. what I got is a 401 error, no authorized, your solution solves the 103 error (page denied) but not the 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: My Question is, You add yourself into the Policy for Web App and after that you are able to access it. I am ok with this but what if you have 50 users, who want to access the site then what you will do, add them into the policy for web app as well?

Comment: surely you will be right but in this case I only need three people to acces the site and this was the only solution I know, of course I will appreciate if someone tells me how to do it correctly.

Comment: couple of things i wana know, what kind of template you are using team site or publishing or? publishing feature turned on? did you created the root level site collection in the web app?

Comment: in this case I was given the site as it is, I didn't create it